# How do I rewrite a class function that mutates default input to not do so?

Tags: python-3.x, object, mutable

For the code below, the inventory in add_item gets bound to the function like detailed here:

["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, inventory: List[Item] = []):
        self.name = name
        self.inventory = inventory

    def add_item(self, item: Item):
        self.inventory.append(item)
```

So this is what happens:

```
Dave.add_item(Book) # has Book
Mary.add_item(Apple) # has Book and Apple
```

So I understand what's going on now but I want Mary to only have the Apple and I don't know how to fix it so that works.

Reading further down that page, I found that doing `self.inventory = []`
works but that would prevent me from initializing items to people in their constructors which I would like to keep since my add_item method only adds one thing at a time.

Comment: You *must not* use `[]` as the default here, as every instance that doesn't specify its own inventory will share that one list.  Make the default `None` (or something else that is distinct from any useful value of the parameter), and conditionally replace that with `[]` (a *non-shared* empty list) in `.__init__()`.

Comment: so like:

    ```def __init__(self, name: str, inventory: List[Item] = None):
        if inventory == None: self.inventory = []
        else: self.inventory = inventory


```

@jasonharper?

Comment: Yes, that's the general idiom for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is the answer for anyone looking in the future. Thanks to @jasonharper for the help in comments.

```
def __init__(self, name: str, inventory: List[Item] = None):         
    if inventory == None: 
        self.inventory = []         
    else: 
        self.inventory = inventory
```